# check if emails match on blur

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I'm trying to check if email field and confirm email field match each other. That is, the user types in their email and then they have to confirm it again. I want the match/validation to happen on blur (when the user presses enter or the textfield loses focus).

Here's my ts file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from './user.interface';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, ValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-email',
    templateUrl: '/app/components/profile/email.component.html',
    styleUrls:['styles.css'], 
})

export class EmailComponent implements OnInit {   

   public user : User;
   Form : FormGroup; 

   ngOnInit() {
        // initialize model here
        this.user = {
            Email: '',
            confirmEmail: ''
        }
         if(this.Form.valid) {
            this.displayErrors = false;
         }
    }

     constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private cookieService: CookieService, private router: Router) {
          this.Form = fb.group({
            email: [''],
            confirmEmail: ['']
        },
        {
            validator: this.matchingEmailsValidator('email', 'confirmEmail')
        });


     }

    save(model: User, isValid: boolean) {
        // call API to save customer
        //save email

    }

    matchingEmailsValidator(emailKey: string, confirmEmailKey: string): ValidatorFn {
        return (group: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {

            let email = group.controls[emailKey];
            let confirmEmail = group.controls[confirmEmailKey];

            if (email.value !== confirmEmail.value) {
                return {
                    mismatch: true
                };
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Here's my view:

```
  <form [formGroup]="Form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="Form.valid && save(Form.value, Form.valid)">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id = "container" class="contain" style="text-align: center">
        <div> 
            <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label id = "rounded" class="item item-input .col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3">
                <input class="email-address-entry form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="name@domain.com" formControlName="email" pattern="^(\\w|[0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_\`{|}~-])+@(\\w|[0-9-])+(?:‌​[.](\\w|[0-9-])+)*$"/>
            </label>
                <p class="Reenter-your-email">Reenter your email to confirm</p>
            <label id = "rounded" class="item item-input">
                <input class="email-address-entry form-control" (blur)="displayErrors=true" name="confirmEmail" type="email" placeholder="name@domain.com" formControlName="confirmEmail" validateEqual="email"/>
            </label> 
            </fieldset>
        </div> 
         <div>
          <label class="entry-invalid">
          <p *ngIf="displayErrors && !Form.get('email').valid">The email you entered does not match.</p>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div (click)="Form.get('email').length > 0 ? save(Form.value, Form.valid) : NaN" class="{{ Form.get('email').length > 0 ? 'container-fluid anchorBottomHighlight' : 'container-fluid anchorBottom'}}">
            <label class="footerLabel">Confirm</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div> 
</form>
```

Currently, with the way it's set up, the validation occurs but it does not get cleared when the correct match is input. I'm wondering how I can setup my view correctly? So the validation message is shown/hidden when the correct match is set and not.

Also it seems like `Form.get('email').length > 0`  is never greater than 0 / never hit, so my label doesn't toggle to be clickable.

I'm using Angular 2 and reactive forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks that you're mixing the two form syntaxes: *template-driven forms* and *model-driven forms*.

Since you're declaring a form model in your class with `FormBuilder`, I'm assuming you want a *model-driven form*.

This means your fields don't need attributes like `[(ngModel)]` or `#EmailAddress`.

Instead of that:

```html
<input type="email" [(ngModel)]="user.EmailAddress"  required #EmailAddress="ngModel">
```

Write this:

```html
<!-- Now I'm using `formControlName` to bind the field to the model -->
<!-- Its value must match one of the names you used in the FormBuilder -->
<input type="email" formControlName="email">
```

ALL of your validators must be declared in the FormBuilder. Not just `matchingEmailsValidator`, but also `required`:

```ts
this.Form = fb.group({
  email: ['', Validators.required],
  confirmEmail: ['', Validators.required]
},
{
  validator: this.matchingEmailsValidator('email', 'confirmEmail')
});
```

Now you can access a field with the following syntax:

```ts
// In the class
this.Form.get('email').value
this.Form.get('email').errors
```

```html
<!-- In the template -->
{{ Form.get('email').value }}
{{ Form.get('email').errors }}
```

You can use these syntaxes to display errors. For example:

```html
<input type="email" formControlName="email">
<p *ngIf="Form.get('email').dirty && Form.get('email').errors.required">
  This field is required.
</p>
```

In the example above, I am displaying an error message if the `email` field has been touched (i.e. the user tried to enter something) AND the `required` error is present.

You can also verify that your validation rules are enforced by inspecting the form's markup with your browser's dev tools. Angular should have added classes like `.ng-invalid` or `.ng-valid` to the `<input>` tags that have validation rules.

Finally, regarding your question to check email match **on blur**. You can't postpone Angular's validation, it will happen in real-time (as the user types). But you could **wait for the blur event to display errors**.

Combining this last advice with my previous example, here's how you could should an error if the email field is empty AND it has lost focus (blur event):

```html
<input type="email" formControlName="email" (blur)="displayErrors=true">
<p *ngIf="displayErrors && Form.get('email').dirty && Form.get('email').errors.required">
  This field is required.
</p>
```

---

**UPDATE(01-FEB-2017) after Euridice posted [this Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/fARkPWrFTZdLXK92iCTU?p=preview):**

- You still have wayyyyy to much validation code in your template. Like I said, ALL VALIDATORS should be declared IN THE FORM MODEL (with the `FormBuilder`). More specifically:

  - The `pattern="..."` attribute in the `email` field should be replaced with `Validators.pattern()` in the form model.
  - What is the `validateEqual="email"` attribute in the `confirmEmail` field? You're not using that anywhere.
- The main problem is your test to display the error message: `*ngIf="displayErrors && !Form.get('email').valid && Form.get('email').error.mismatch"`.

  - First of all, the property is `errors` with an "s", not `error`.
  - Also, your custom validator is setting the error **on the form itself**, NOT on the email field. This means you should retrieve your `mismatch` custom error from `Form.errors.mismatch`, NOT `Form.get('email').errors.mismatch`.

Here's the updated, working Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/dTjcqlm6rZQxA7E0yZLa?p=preview

Comment: Could you go over in more depth about how to use this: this.Form.get('email').errors? Thank you so much for your 'mini tutorial'. Super helpful!

Comment: E.g. if I wanted to do something like in my ts file: if(Form.valid) {
                    this.displayErrors = false; 
                }

Comment: I have amended my example to answer your comment. Would you mind marking this answer as the accepted answer if you think it does the trick?

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to clear the forms validation error message after it's appeared and the form is now valid (the email addresses match). How do I clear the error message? 
I'm trying to set displayErrors=false when !form.valid but it's not detecting the changes to the form in realtime.

Comment: I updated my view code but still having issues with onBlur

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: there's no `onBlur` event; the event is called `blur` and you can use the syntax I provided to listen to it. As for clearing the message once the error disappears, it should happen automatically: once the error disappears, the `Form.get('email').errors.XXXX` property disappears, and the `*ngIf` will remove the message from the DOM. Maybe you're not testing the right error? The example I provided tests the `required` error, maybe you need to test the `mismatch` error?

Comment: Even with the mismatch error for ngIf, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please submit a Plunkr and I'll take a look.

Comment: Please go to Example Form in the plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/fARkPWrFTZdLXK92iCTU?p=preview. With the setup you suggested, the validation is completely broken. I think there's an issue with the model being invalid?

Comment: That's because you have several syntax and logic errors. I have updated my answer with the solution and a working Plunkr.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! Also I'm sorry about the duplicate, I deleted it. Thank you so much again!

Comment: You could simplify it and also prevent some errors in template using `Form.get('email').hasError('required')`. :)